# Fastest algorithm to compute isogeny

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E/GF(p)$ and $E'/GF(p')$ are two isogenous elliptic curves($\#E=\#E'$). We know that there exist the map

> $$\psi : E \to E'$$

Suppose that we haven't any information about degree of $\psi$.

What is the complexity of best algorithm for computing $\psi$?

(I think that I saw an algorithm with complexity like $O({Max(p,p')}^{1.5}{log(p)}^c)$.)

Comment: It doesn't make sense for two elliptic curves defined over different fields to be isogenous, you want $p=p'$ in your notation.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch, If $p$ and $p'$ aren't same can we find such map?

Comment: You definitely want the characteristics to be the same.